# How to predict size for output of SslEncryptPacket

Tags: ssl, winapi, schannel

Usually Win32 API can tell what is the length of output buffer required. One need just pass 0 as buffer length and API returns error BUFFER_TOO_SMALL and number of bytes required.

But it is not the same with [SslEncryptPacket](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468663.aspx). It just returns error about small buffer and that's all.

There is also [SslLookupCipherLengths](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468679.aspx) which I suppose should be used for that, but documentation gives no clue about how to calculate output buffer having that info.

Maybe you can tell ? Usually I would reserve + kilobyte , but in my situation I need to know exactly.

Comment: The maximum size of an SSL message is in the vicinity of 16k, depending slightly on the cipher suite. You may be able to get that exact information out of the MS SSL API, I'm not an expert on it.

Comment: To get an idea, you might start with a buffer of length 1 (of course this is ridiculously small, you could start with smth like 512), and every tine the func call returns `BUFFER_TOO_SMALL`, double the buffer size, until you no longer get the error. After that to check if this isn't too large, you could decrease its size till you get the error again, and thus get the exact needed buffer size.

Answer (score 1):

You probably already know that in order to go through the TLS/SSL handshake, you repeatedly call SSPI->[InitializeSecurityContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/initializesecuritycontext--schannel) (on the client side) or SSPI->[AcceptSecurityContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/acceptsecuritycontext--schannel) (on the server side).

Once the function returns SEC_E_OK, you should call SSPI->[QueryContextAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/querycontextattributes--schannel) with SECPKG_ATTR_STREAM_SIZES to determine the sizes of the header and trailer. It also tells you the number of SecBuffers to use for the SSPI->[EncryptMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthn/encryptmessage--general) function, and it tells you the maximum size of the message that you can pass to EncryptMessage.

As I understand, the values that are returned may vary depending on the type of encryption that the OS chooses for the connection. I'm not intimately familiar with TLS/SSL but I think it uses 5 bytes for the header, 36 for the footer and 16384 for the maximum message length. You mileage may vary, so that's why you should call QueryContextAttribute(... SECPKG_ATTR_STREAM_SIZES ...).